# Why can't I install 10.04 on a system that already has 8.04?

Tags: 10.04, installation, dual-boot, 8.04

Ubuntu 10.04 is beautiful. I love it. I am dying to install it on my PC, alongside the existing Ubuntu 8.04 (from which I write this message right now).

But... it won't let me!

When I reach the partitioning stage (manual!) Ubuntu 10.04 sees my two HDDs as one RAID volume.

It doesn't see all the partitions I already have in place in /dev/sda and /dev/sdb.

Even Windows 7 doesn't behave like this... (yes, I actually managed to install Windows 7 64-bit in dual-boot configuration with Ubuntu 8.04 on this same system).

Note: GParted on Ubuntu 10.04 (live CD) sees the partition intended for Ubuntu 10.04 (/dev/sda4) perfectly, but is unable to format it.

Note: I also removed that partition trying to reformat it via GParted once 10.04 LiveCD is loaded. It didn't help.

I believe that the problem lies in Ubuntu "deciding for me" that the HDDs should be "seen" as a RAID, hence any partition is seen by GParted as "busy" or "locked".

Any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: Using Ubuntu 10.10 at least, can you connect the 2 HDD in another PC and using a Live CD format them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. See solution [here](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/ubuntu-63/why-cant-i-install-10-04-on-a-system-that-already-has-8-04-a-853016/).

Comment: While this does answer your question (and it's good you posted and accepted it), [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 1):

Since the drive was part of a raid configuration at some time, you need to remove the RAID meta-data from the drive. I had to do this with a used drive I purchased. The procedure I followed erases the data on the drive. However, it does work. The raid meta-data should be towards the end of the drive space. This command erases the last 10GB of the drive when run as root, but you should back up your drive to preserve the data you do not want to lose:

Please replace `/dev/???` with the correct drive, such as `/dev/sda`

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero bs=1M seek=150000 skip=150000 of=/dev/???
```

Comment: your answer may explain the mystery. Thanks and +1. Unfortunately, erasing **all** the data on the drive is not an option for me. But... did you say this procedure would erase **only** the last 10GB?

Comment: No, I said it would erase the drive. The 150000 is the last 10GB of the drive, but I think by erasing that with this command, it erases the entire drive